# PostgreSql call stored proc with multiple result sets

Tags: c#, postgresql, stored-procedures, npgsql

I am migrating an MSSQL db to PostgreSql. MSSQL db has a stored procedure that returns multiple result set. To migrate that to Postgres, I passed in refcursors as params to retrieve multiple result sets e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.test_proc(IN par_id bigint, INOUT ref_cur1 refcursor, INOUT ref_cur2 refcursor)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    OPEN ref_cur1 FOR
    SELECT * From firsttable where firsttable.id = par_id;
    OPEN ref_cur2 FOR
    SELECT * from secondtable where lnkid = par_id;
END;
$BODY$;
```

I am trying to call that stored proc in my .net application using Npgsql

```
using (var lConn = GetConnection()) {
                    using (var trans = lConn.BeginTransaction()) {
                        using (var cmd = GetCommand("call public.test_proc(@par_id, @ref_cur1, @ref_cur2)", lConn, trans, System.Data.CommandType.Text)) {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@par_id", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = id;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter() {
                                ParameterName = "@ref_cur1",
                                NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor,
                                Value = "ref_cur1",
                                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput
                            });

                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter() {
                                ParameterName = "@ref_cur2",
                                NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor,
                                Value = "ref_cur2",
                                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput
                            });

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            cmd.CommandText = $"fetch all \"ref_cur1\"";
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    string name = (string)reader["name"];
                                    DateTime dtTime = (DateTime)reader["createddate"];
                                }
                            }

                            reader.Close();

                            cmd.CommandText = $"fetch all \"ref_cur2\"";
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //This throws exception

                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    string name = (string)reader["description"];
                                    int lnkId = (int)reader["lnkid"];
                                }
                            }
                            reader.Close();

                        }
                    }
                }
```

I am able to read values of ref_cur1 but get following exception on trying to retrieve second cursor

> Can't write CLR type System.Int64 with handler type TextHandler

I am a newbie with postgres and most of the above sql and code is from different google searches so let me know if there is a better way of returning multiple results from an SP.

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible.

I think you'd be better off opening a single DB connection and making async calls to the DB for each query.  You'll see a performance bump doing it this way as well.  Honestly for such a simple query I'd ditch the stored proc and go with Entity Framework.  That at least takes you down a path of being DB agnostic.  Then you're async calls would be to linq queries instead of stored procs.

Comment: Thanks spyder1329, The query here is just an example and actual stored proc has more to it. Also I have to use stored procs as we are migrating an old db which is full of stored procs and we need to keep code changes to minimum.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want a function (rather than a procedure) which *returns* two refcursors - rather than sending refcursors to PostgreSQL; something like [this](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure) should do the trick.

Comment: Async or non-async I/O doesn't have anything to do with it, and I don't really see what the recommendation to use Entity Framework has to do with this question.

Comment: yes @ShayRojansky, that function does work, and purely for cosmetic reasons (keep object types similar in old and new db), i wanted to avoid swapping storedprocs with functions. Also correct me if i'm wrong but even storedprocs with inout ref cursors should work (at least pgAdmin doesn't complain) when I do this 
CALL public.test_proc(
 1, 
 'ref_cur1', 
 'ref_cur2'
);

Fetch all in "ref_cur1";

Fetch all in "ref_cur2";

Comment: It may work - I've not tried this somewhat unusual pattern of passing a refcursor into a procedure. In any case regarding the specific error above, try creating new commands when executing  the FETCH ALL rather than reusing the same one you used with CALL - I don't have the complete code sample but I'm guessing there's some parameter mismatch going on there.

Comment: Shay, using postgres and npgsql first time, so this approach may not be best. let me know if there's a better way of returning multiple result sets from stored proc and calling them in C# via npgsql.

Comment: The usual approach for returning multiple results is what I linked to above - a function returning two refcursors, and then calling FETCH ALL on the results with Npgsql. Your approach may also work (see my suggestions for fixing your code).

Answer (score 0):

I could not make things work with stored procedure so just ended up reverting back to using a function instead, for which same Npgsql code successfully fetches multiple cursors. The only change I had to do was to use

> var cmd = GetCommand("public.test_proc"

for function instead of

> var cmd = GetCommand("call public.test_proc(@par_id, @ref_cur1, @ref_cur2)"

for stored proc

Thanks @ShayRojansky for assisting with it.

Comment: @ShayRojansky on another note, the C# sample [link](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_cs_result_sets), doesn't work as the reader always holds the cursor unnamed cursor instead of the result set and requires an additional fetch all in 'unamed portal 1' to get the actual result set. Any idea what could the reason be for that?